# '<<name of method>>' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I want to independently overload `operator+` to concatenate 2 double chained lists. My idea is to obtain the address of the first element from the first list and the address of the first element from the second list.

In `DoubleChainedList` class, except the constructor, destructor and the next 4 methods which are working fine, I made a method called `get_prim` which is supposed to get me the address of the first element from the specified list. Then, using the method `get_current` I want to move through the first list until it ends while adding in the third list the elements, and then apply the same principle to the second list.

But I have a problem, I get

```
'get_prim' was not declared in this scope
```

and

```
'get_current' was not declared in this scope
```

at the bolded tagged lines (see the code below) when I compile. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

//Create node class
class Node
{
private:
    float value;         
    Node *back;        
    Node *next;       
public:
    Node *set_value (Node *x, float element) { x->value=element; return x; }
    float get_value (Node *x) { return x->value; }
    Node *set_back (Node *x) { return x->back; }
    Node *set_next (Node *x) { return x->next; }
    Node *set_back_nod (Node *x, Node *y) { x->back=y; return x; }
    Node *set_next_nod (Node *x, Node *y) { x->next=y; return x; }
    void next_to_2next (Node *x) { x->next=x->next->next; }
    void next_back_to_origins (Node *x) { x->next->back=x; }
};

//Create list class
class DoubleChainedList : public Node
{
private:
    Node *prim;       
    Node *ultim;    
public:
    DoubleChainedList() { prim=NULL; ultim=prim; }           //Constructor
    ~DoubleChainedList();                                    //Destructor
    void insert_back(float element);                         //Inserts an element at the end of the list
    void delete_element_from_position(int delete_position);  //Deletes from the list the element whose position is equal to "delete_position"
    void show_left_right();                                  //Shows the list from the first element to the last one
    void show_right_left();                                  //Shows the list from the last element to the first one
    Nod *get_prim (DoubleChainedList myList) { return this->prim; };    //Intended to obtain the address of the first element from "myList"
    Nod *get_current (Node *x) { return set_next(x); };                  //Intended to move me through the list
};

DoubleChainedList operator+ (DoubleChainedList myList1, DoubleChainedList myList2)
{
    DoubleChainedList myList3;
    Nod *current1,*current2;
    current1=get_prim(myList1); // ERROR OVER HERE!
    current2=get_prim(myList2);
    cout<<get_value(current1)<<" "; // ERROR OVER HERE!
    cout<<get_value(current2)<<" ";
    return myList3;
}

int main()
{
    int i,number_elem_myList1,number_elem_myList2,element;
    DoubleChainedList myList1,myList2,myList3;
    cin>>number_elem_myList1;
    for (i=0;i<number_elem_myList1;i++)
    {
        cin>>element;
        myList1.insert_back(element);
    }
    cin>>number_elem_myList2;
    for (i=0;i<number_elem_myList2;i++)
    {
        cin>>element;
        myList2.insert_back(element);
    }
    myList3=myList1+myList2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you try to compile that code, you get a lot more errors than just those two...

Comment: @Dukeling: Of course I get a lot more errors on the code posted above, but I cut it off just to make it easier to understand for another person. I specified that all the other things are working fine and also tried to comment the essential parts. If you don't understand something, ask me. Also, the function for overloading the "+" operator isn't finished yet because I'm stuck on this part.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `operator+=` as a member function, you can have access to the other list's variables.

I would implement `operator+=`, then traverse the other list, appending the other list's nodes to this list.

And pass the other list as `const &`.

Comment: I have to concatenate them in a third list, not to modify the first one.

Comment: Try this: 1) Create empty list_3. 2) Use list_3 += list_1.  3) Use list_3 += list_2.

Comment: This seems a good solution, but harder to implement (at least for me). Using my idea, I would obtain the address of the first element from the first list, add the element to third list using the method "insert_back" and repeat that until the first list ends, then the same for the second list. Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Functions called with e.g. `someObject.function(...)` or `someObject->function(...)` (where `someObject` is respectively either an object or a pointer to an object of some class that has a `function(...)` function) have direct access to the members of `someObject`.

So functions that are members of a class doesn't need to be passed an object of that class as parameter, unless you want to work with 2 objects in that function.

The functions of `Node` should probably look more like:

```
void set_value (float element) { value = element; }
float get_value () { return value; }
Node *set_back () { return back; }
Node *set_next () { return next; }
void set_back_nod (Node *y) { back = y; }
void set_next_nod (Node *y) { next = y; }
void next_to_2next () { next = next->next; }
void next_back_to_origins () { next->back = this; }
```

Also, `get_prim`:

```
Node *get_prim() { return prim; };
```

Which then leads to a `operator+` which looks more like: (`const &` as Thomas suggested)

```
DoubleChainedList operator+ (const DoubleChainedList &myList1,
                             const DoubleChainedList &myList2)
{
    DoubleChainedList myList3;
    Node *current1, *current2;
    current1 = myList1.get_prim();
    current2 = myList2.get_prim();
    cout << current1->get_value() << " ";
    cout << current2->get_value() << " ";
    // ...
    return myList3;
}
```

Using `operator+=` as Thomas suggested is probably also a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the program as follows, but I still have a problem. If I try to display the list outside the procedure "operator+", I get "Segmentation fault" (when I debugged the program it happened immediately after this instruction: "myList3=myList1+myList2;"). If I display it inside that procedure, everything's OK. I think that this is happening because of that "return" statement and because I return a temporary object which will no longer exists after the "operator+" procedure ends, but I don't know how to fix that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Create node class
class Node
{
private:
    float value;         
    Node *back;        
    Node *next;       
public:
    Node *set_value (float element) { value=element; return this; }
    float get_value () { return value; }
    Node *set_back () { return back; }
    Node *set_next () { return next; }
    Nod *set_back_node (Node *y) { back=y; return this; }
    Nod *set_next_node (Node *y) { next=y; return this; }
    void next_to_2next () { next=next->next; }
    void next_back_to_origins () { next->back=this; }
};

//Create list class
class DoubleChainedList : public Node
{
private:
    Node *prim;       
    Node *ultim;    
public:
    DoubleChainedList() { prim=NULL; ultim=prim; }           //Constructor
    ~DoubleChainedList();                                    //Destructor
    void insert_back(float element);                         //Inserts an element at the end of the list
    void delete_element_from_position(int delete_position);  //Deletes from the list the element whose position is equal to "delete_position"
    void show_left_right();                                  //Shows the list from the first element to the last one
    void show_right_left();                                  //Shows the list from the last element to the first one
    Node *get_prim () { return prim; }                       //Intended to obtain the address of the first element from a list
};

DoubleChainedList operator+ (DoubleChainedList myList1, DoubleChainedList myList2)
{
    DoubleChainedList myList3;
    Node *current1,*current2,*current3;
    current1=myList1.get_prim();
    current2=myList2.get_prim();
    while ((current1!=NULL)||(current2!=NULL))
    {
        if (current1!=NULL)
        {
            myList3.insert_back(current1->get_value());
            current1=current1->set_next();
        }
        else
            if (current2!=NULL)
            {
                myList3.insert_back(current2->get_value());
                current2=current2->set_next();
            }
    }
    //myList3.show_left_right();
    //cout<<endl;
    //myList3.show_right_left();
    return myList3;
}

int main()
{
    int i,number_elem_myList1,number_elem_myList2,element;
    DoubleChainedList myList1,myList2,myList3;
    cin>>nr_elem_lista1;
    for (i=0;i<number_elem_myList1;i++)
    {
        cin>>element;
        myList1.insert_back(element);
    }
    cin>>number_elem_myList2;
    for (i=0;i<number_elem_myList2;i++)
    {
        cin>>element;
        myList2.insert_back(element);
    }
    myList3=myList1+myList2;
    myList3.show_left_right();
    myList3.show_right_left();
    return 0;
}
```

@Dukeling modified the methods of the "Node" class as you said (and of course the program where necessary) and it's OK, too.

I can post the full code if is someone interested, but it has more than 200 lines, the name of variables/dates, procedures/methods and also some comments wrote in Romanian (my natural language) and it would be harder for someone new to understand it.